# Choosing an Android Layout

Tags: java, android, layout

I am trying to achieve a specific layout in Android and I am not sure where to begin. The layout I am trying to get is something akin to this: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6116499/Layout.jpg

In this case, the black boxes will be containers of other components. Normally, in java I would create custom JFrames and attach them to a grid layout. I am not really sure if there is a corollary for Android. If there is, I am not sure what it is called. It is worth mentioning that the layout should be able to expand inward or outward with the components anchored to the outer edge.

So here is my question: What layout should I use? Furthermore, what control in Android functions as a collection of other controls like the JFrame does?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive the same using [Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html). Just that you would need to take care of components alignment in multiple layouts and phone factors. The other way of doing it is writing your own custom layout. There are multipe tutorials available for this. 
[This](http://arpitonline.com/blog/2012/07/01/creating-custom-layouts-for-android/) is one of them. You can also understand further from the youtube video posted. [Google IO - Writing custom views](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYtB6mlu7vA&feature=player_embedded)